# Change placeholder every time when text is erased

Tags: javascript, html

How to change the placeholder in Textarea every time text is erased?

I have an array of strings that changes placeholder every time page is refreshed, How can I do the same when text is erased in real-time?

```js
const placeholders = [
  "Hello World",
  "This is Placeholder",
  "Type Something..."
]

function randomPlaceholder(array) {
  // radomizing value from array
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (array.length));
  document.getElementById("txt-area").placeholder = array[x];
}
randomPlaceholder(placeholders);
```

```html
<textarea name="" id="txt-area"></textarea>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/egqjd43r/

Comment: How about an onchange event and checking if the value of `txt-area` to see if the length is 0? I'm not sure there is an event for the complete removal of the text area content so you'll need to manually check and then update as necessary.

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks This is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: No judgement, but it was downvoted because it's a very basic question and this website is supposed to answer questions that *aren't* covered by other resources, especially basic tutorials. (this is also why I didn't post an actual answer)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const placeholders = [
  "Hello World",
  "This is Placeholder",
  "Type Something..."
]

function randomPlaceholder(array) {
  // radomizing value from array
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((array.length)-0)+0);
  document.getElementById("txt-area").placeholder = array[x];
}
randomPlaceholder(placeholders);
```

```html
<textarea name="" id="txt-area"></textarea>
```

Comment: This will not work. I think you didn't get the question.

Comment: I got your point added new once.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const placeholders = [
  "Hello World",
  "This is Placeholder",
  "Type Something..."
]

function randomPlaceholder(array) {
  // radomizing value from array
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((array.length) - 0) + 0);
  document.getElementById("txt-area").placeholder = array[x];
}

randomPlaceholder(placeholders);

if (document.getElementById("txt-area").placeholder == "") {
  if (document.getElementById("txt-area").value == '') {
    document.getElementById("txt-area").value = randomPlaceholder(placeholders);
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea name="" id="txt-area"></textarea>
```